# Finding a sequence of digits in the decimal expansion of a rational number

Tags: number-theory

I'd like to know how to find a sequence of digits (say up to 32 digits with each digit chosen from $\{0,\dots,9\}$) in the decimal expansion of some $p/q$ with $p < q < 10000$.

I've tried brute force methods, checking each $1/9999$, $2/9999$, etc. but it takes way too long. Any ideas?

Comment: long division heh

Comment: Could you be a bit more specific please?

Comment: The decimal expansion is periodic, with the period depending on q. You'll need to choose specific values q to guarantee that the period is of length at least 32 at all, if your sequence is not periodic.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You won't always be able to find a fraction $\frac pq$ with $p < q < 10000$ containing your sequence, but if you can do it, here's how.

First, if any such fraction contains your sequence at all, then some such fraction must *begin* with your sequence. To see this, notice that if $\frac pq$ contains your sequence starting from the $k^{\text{th}}$ digit after the decimal, then $\frac{10p \bmod q}{q}$ (the fractional part of $\frac{10p}{q}$) contains it starting from the $(k-1)^{\text{th}}$ digit.

So if you're looking for a sequence $s_1s_2\dots s_n$, we might as well look for a fraction beginning $0.s_1s_2\dots s_n$, so let's find good approximations of the rational number $r = 0.s_1s_2\dots s_n5$. (I add the $5$ at the end to make $r$ the midpoint of the interval of all real numbers beginning with this sequence.)

We can find good approximations of $r$ from its continued fraction expansion. This is an expression of the form $$r = a_0 + \frac1{a_1 + \frac1{a_2 + \frac1{a_3 + \frac1{\ddots}}}}$$ which we can find iteratively: find $a_0$ by taking $\lfloor r \rfloor$, and then finding the continued fraction expansion of $\frac1{r - a_0}$ to get $a_1, a_2, \dots$.

Because $r$ is rational, eventually this process stops, giving us exactly $r$. But truncating this expansion, but using less of the sequence $a_0, a_1, a_2, \dots$, gives us approximations $\frac{p_0}{q_0}, \frac{p_1}{q_1}, \frac{p_2}{q_2}, \dots$ where $$\frac{p_0}{q_0} = a_0, \quad \frac{p_1}{q_1} = a_0 + \frac1{a_1}, \quad \frac{p_2}{q_2} = a_0 + \frac1{a_1 + \frac1{a_2}}, \quad \dots$$
See [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Continued_fraction). These also satisfy the recurrence $\frac{p_{k+2}}{q_{k+2}} = \frac{p_k + a_{k+2} p_{k+1}}{q_k + a_{k+2} p_{k+1}}$.

These are best approximations in the sense that $\left|r - \frac{p_k}{q_k}\right| < \left|r - \frac{p'}{q'}\right|$ for any $p', q'$ with $q' < q_k$. So we can find better and better approximations for $r$, and if eventually one of them starts with $0.s_1s_2\dots s_n$, we're done.

It's possible that we've gotten to approximations $\frac{p_k}{q_k}$ where $q_k \ge 10000$ and we *still* don't have a good enough approximation of $r$. If that's the case, we give up: by the best approximation inequality,no $\frac pq$ with $q < 10000$ can be good enough.

Finally, we can end up in the rare but annoying edge case where $\frac{p_k}{q_k}$ is the last approximation with $q_k < 10000$, and is not good enough, but $\frac{p_{k+1}}{q_{k+1}}$ *is* good enough (and has $q_{k+1} \ge 10000$). If that's the case, we have two last resorts:

- The semi-convergents: see [this blog post](https://shreevatsa.wordpress.com/2011/01/10/not-all-best-rational-approximations-are-the-convergents-of-the-continued-fraction/). These are computed by taking $\frac{p_{k-1} + n p_k}{q_{k-1} + n q_k}$ for $1 \le n < a_{k+1}$, and *also* satisfy the best approximation inequality.
- If that's still inconclusive, then let $\frac{p}{q}$ be the best approximation we've found so far, and try denominators of $q+1, q+2, \dots, 9999$ by brute force. To try a denominator of $m$, take the fractions $\frac{\lfloor{rm}\rfloor}{m}$ and $\frac{\lceil{rm}\rceil}{m}$ and see if either of them work.